# Error in sending mail from server

Tags: email, centos7, exim

i have a Centos 7 VPS with Exim installed. I am not receiving email from server because of the following error:

```
2018-01-06 15:50:06 1eXqjW-0000hE-7v Sender identification U=mailnull D=-system- S=mailnull
2018-01-06 15:50:06 1eXqjW-0000hE-7v Sender identification U=mailnull D=-system- S=mailnull
2018-01-06 15:50:06 1eXqjW-0000hE-7v ** ***@gmail.com <root@localhost> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.68.27] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass\n550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the\n550-5.7.1 message has been blocked. Please visit\n550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more\n550 5.7.1 information. z58si6841575qtj.216 - gsmtp
2018-01-06 15:50:06 1eXqjW-0000hE-7v Frozen (delivery error message)
2018-01-06 15:50:06 1eXqjV-0000gI-Nt Completed
```

Seems that mail is going out as root@localhost, how can i configure exim or server so he sends email from a domain?

Edit: I sent a mail to mail-tester.com this is the main error:

We didn't find a mail server (MX Record) behind your domain name localhost.
We check if there is a mail server (MX Record) behind your domain name localhost.
You may want to publish a DNS record (MX type) for the domain name localhost or use a different bounce email address.

Comment: Set the hostname of the machine correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I configured the hostname correctly, but then i had to do fix things: Add a PTR record (reverse DNS), add MX record and add TXT record for spf entry to the DNS zone